# How get object from indices in Areablock?

Tags: pimcore

I have Pimcore\Model\Document\Tag\Areablock with tree elements table of indices:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["type"]=>
      string(8) "newsData"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "wysiwyg"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(12) "videogallery"
    }
}
```

How could I get newsData object from Areablock object?

I coudn't find function in Areablock for that and don't know how to get date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Areabricks are not subelements of the actual areablock, but are direct elements of current document. Their names are just differently constructed.

```
$areablock = $this->areablock("yourAreablock");

foreach ($areablock->getData() as $brick) {
    if ($brick["type"] == "yourAreaBrickName") {
        $nameOfTheEditableInBrick = "bigtitle";
        $indexOfTheAreaBrick = $brick["key"];
        // This is your element
        $subelement = $this->document->getElement($nameOfTheEditableInBrick . $areablock->getName() . $brick["key"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: For Pimcore 5 Sites:
`$this->document->getElement( $block_name.':'.$brick[ 'key' ].'.'.$editable_name);`